# error while running SOLR application

Tags: linux, logging, solr, directory, port

i am newbie on SOLR, i want to start my SOLR via terminal ubuntu but it always give error message :

```
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 S till not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
```

tail: cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
i try to use this script `service solr start` and `./solr start` but the result still same, any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: try running on some different port with command `solr start -p 8984`

Comment: still error like like my thread bro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this increasing the RAM of my virtual machine.

Comment: i fixed it by swapping my RAM of my VM, and it works like a charm, thanks fo the clue bro.